# How to get missed call event in Android?

Tags: android

How to capture a missed call event in Android?. The notification bar can show the missed call. Using telephony manager and phone state listener, its possible to read the phone state as IDLE, RINGING and OFFHOOK. But how to know whether it was a missed call?. Please help

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?  I am also trying to do the same, not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

set a different flag variable for RINGING and OFFHOOK.

Check the flag when the phone comes to IDLE in the phone state listener.

make sure you have a keydown listener for call cut button ..

if the flag is set for RINGING and Free from call cut then its a  miss call...

this is just a list of methods.. the library supports the function for phone listener and keydown methods.

Comment: how to get the key down listener for call cut button?

Comment: public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  switch (keyCode) {
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL:
               //your code 
           return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

Comment: this listener is not catching the EndCall event

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you get any notifications for missed calls.

You can get events of `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` from 
keep a track of events in this order

`EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` to `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` to `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`

Then check [CallLog](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html) and get your missed call details from there.